# How to create a Zoom effect on an image with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal-8

Hello I have a site with Drupal 8 and I want that when a user rolls over his mouse or moves his doight on an image, there is a zoom. Exactly as in the example below. See the "Inner Zoom" effect :

http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/examples

I have the Botstrap 3 theme. The ideal is that the image is displayed on a page in a format and resolution defined in Drupal 8 and that when I hover or touch the image, it will be zoomed in format and original resolution.

How to do this ? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of what you've already tried.

Comment: I don't think you should use JS for zoom, you could use plain css

Comment: I really don't see how not to use JS. Have you looked at the example ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your looking for something like this. By the way there is no point of using js for such instance. You can simply get it by using the below css code.

```
img {   height: 100px;   width: 100px;   max-width: 120px;  
-webkit-transform: scale(1);   -moz-transform: scale(1);   -ms-transform: scale(1);   -o-transform: scale(1);   transform: scale(1);   webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;  
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   transition: all 0.5s ease-out; }
```

Say your image is inside a div and the class being used is box. And you want to obtain the zoom effects. Then you can go ahead by using the below code as well.

```
.box:hover {
  /* background: #0088E0; */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 16px 20px 0px rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 16px 20px 0px rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.75);
  /* box-shadow: 0px 16px 20px 0px rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.75); */
  box-shadow: 0 16px 20px 0 rgb(2,138,69);
}

.box:hover .icon img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

Comment: Your code does not answer my question. See the "Inner Zoom" effect http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/examples